# Счетчик времени во всплывающем окне

Tags: javascript

Не получается сделать в попапе счетчик времени (секунд), чтобы по прошествии 3-х секунд закрывалось окно. Хочу, чтобы тикало 3, потом 2, потом 1 и окно закрылвась, вот это тикание как реализовать? Знаю что через сетинтервал, но не получается.

Comment: Ну так подробнее опишите. Что делали, как делали. А непонятно вам с самых азов JS объяснять или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var counter = 3;
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){     
    console.log(counter--);// вваш способ вывода отсчёта 
    if(counter==0){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log('close'); // ваш способ закрытия 
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Только `counter--` лучше выполнять уже после сравнения, чтобы "3, 2, 1, close" не превращалось в "3, 2, close".